# <Document Name> has been changed alert - SharePoint 2010

Tags: document-library, alert

I have uploaded a new document in a library. The document has no properties.

But I get `"<Document> name has been changed"` alert email.

This is the first time the document is uploaded. I thought I would get a `<Document Name> has been added` alert.

Is there any reason why the alert was `<Document name> has been changed` and not `<Document Name> has been added`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the second answer [to this question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0c6428c-efe5-4f77-8f86-451b26f21c64/alerts-on-document-library-sometimes-not-being-sent?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) on the MS TechNet forum, only the latest change will be sent as an alert.

Lu Zou says: "In SharePoint, if multiple changes are made to a document before the alert mail is generated, SharePoint alert will only send the latest change that was made. This is to prevent spamming with too many alerts or too many changes in a digest when people hit “save” again and again."

I'm struggling with this problem as well, but it looks like removing the alert and creating a workflow to handle it instead would be the only workaround.